# Items must be empty before using Items source with showdialog

Tags: list, mvvm, itemscontrol, showdialog

The problem is recurrent, unfortunately, I didn't find the solution for my case :
I use an itemcontrols in a synchronized dialog (using showdialog command). The itemControls shall be defined as soon as the dialog is opened (or before, but then, I have this error).
In this case, how can I initialize my dialog, then update the itemcontrols with my existing list, since, when I open the dialog, this is synchron and my code is not reachable until the dialog is closed?

Comment: Probably because you have added some Items to your ItemsControl in XAML? This has nothing to do with sync/async. Also please provide some [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

lokusking is actually right :
I forgot to add encapsulations ItemTemplate and DataTemplate, so the labels in the control were considered as data, instead of templates. Now, it works.
Thanks